# Trouble understanding JS recursive countdown function from freeCodeCamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

So, I've already understood the *idea* of recursion in JavaScript (having a **function that *loops* itself** until it reaches a *base* condition, at which point it stops and **returns the final result**), but I'm having a bit of a headache when I apply that to the actual syntax of trying to apply it to **create arrays**.

Let's use [this countdown exercise from freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-countdown) as an example. This is the correct result:

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

The idea here is obviously to have a function to **count down from a given *n* to 1**. I understand the idea, but I have a couple of questions:

**1 -** Why is the array **declared as a constant** and **assigned to the recursion call**? Shouldn't the array be better declared *outside* as a *variable* (since it *changes* value)– and doesn't its current position mean that it is declared (and over-written) *every time* the recursion takes place?

**2 -** I get the unshifting of the current value, but why is it declared *after* the recursive call? Shouldn't it be positioned *before* (one line above) so as to **unshift the value *before* the function loops** itself?

**3 -** Similarly, why is the full final array returned *within the else loop*? Shouldn't it be better returned outside, or **on the base condition above**, so as to not be returned *every time* the function loops?

As it is, my understanding is that when *n* reaches 0, the loop should return an *empty* array, and **not the full array that has been created** with the recursion.

~ ~ ~

***FINAL EDIT / UNDERSTANDING:*** Thanks to every answer! So, if my current understanding is correct, recursion **does not loop** the function, as I initially thought – instead, it sort of *"opens"* a call of *"chained functions"* that goes *downwards* until it finds and **resolves the base case**.

When that *"base"* case or function is resolved, the chain goes *"up"*, so to say, **resolving each recursive step above**, *.unshifting* each n value, and returning the resulting array *"upwards"*,  until we reach the *initial n value*, at which point the final array is returned, and the function is exited.

I think I (sort of) got the point now! Actually writing recursive functions won't be easier though, but I have a better grasp of how the process actually takes place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to clarify how the code is working a little. Hopefully, the explanation clears up your questions a bit. Let's start with the most basic case:

**`countdown(0)`** - When you call `countdown(0)` your if-block runs and returns an empty array `[]`. So we see that `countdown(0)` outputs `[]`. This is the base case.

Next, let's imagine we call the function again, this time as:

**`countdown(1)`** - In this scenario the `else` block runs. We see that it calls **`countdown(0)`**, which means the interpreter executes the function again, passing `n` as `0`. Above we saw what happens when `countdown(0)` is called, it returns an empty array `[]`, so that's what gets assigned to `arr` within the `else` block. We then unshift `n` (which is `1` here) onto this empty array, which adds `1` to the start of the array stored in `arr`. This is then returned. So we say that `countdown(1)` outputs `[1]`.

Now let's see what happens if we were to call the function again with `2`:

**`countdown(2)`** - Again, the `else` block runs, triggering a call to **`countdown(1)`**. We saw above what occurs when this is called, we get back an array with `[1]`, which is stored in the local variable `arr`, and we then `.unshift(2)` so that `2` is added to the beginning of the array which we then return. So we see that `countdown(2)` returns `[2, 1]`.

---

When thinking about recursion, it can be helpful to think of it as breaking down your input until it's at a small enough value that it can't be broken down anymore (your base case). Once you hit that, you work your way back up, stitching together your previous calls now that you have "solved" the sub-problems.

To answer your questions more directly:

1. `arr` is assigned to the recursive call so that we can build upon the results it returned. If `countdown(1)` returns `[1]`, then we can build onto that result by storing it in `arr` and unshift `2` onto it to calculate `countdown(2)`. It could have been made `let`, but `const` is commonly used if the variable doesn't need to be reassigned. We don't want to move `arr` outside of the function as then calling `countdown()` multiple times will modify the same global array. You would also need to change your code so that we can gradually "build-up" the result by further recursive calls if you did that also, which is more of a "loop mindset" than a "recursive mindset".
2. Moving the `.unshift()` component before the recursive call wouldn't work as you wouldn't have anything to unshift to. The recursive call is what provides you with the array result of `countdown(n-1)` so that you can build onto that later by using `.unshift()`.
3. Returning your array in the `else` block is what allows you to obtain results when `n` is greater than `0`. In the `countdown(1)` example above, we need to `return arr` so that it outputs `[1]`. This needs to be in the `else` block because we're returning `arr` which is defined in that `else`-block (and hence can't be accessed outside of it).

Comment: Thanks man! This was the clearest response – I'm still wrapping my head around it, but this seems to be the way to go. **Here's a final question: I tried to include a console.log(arr) just before return arr** (so as to log the countdown without having to console.log(countdown(n)) outside) but then it logs a [1] within countdown(0), which seems strange to me. Any idea why that might happen, and how to avoid it?

Comment: @Ferpalaciosd What value are you originally calling `countdown()` with? If you do `countdown(0)` and have `console.log(arr)` before the `return arr;` in the else-block, then you would never see the log, as the if-block runs when `0` is passed, not the else block where the log is placed. If you called it with `countdown(1)`, then the else block would run calling `countdown(0)`, which doesn't log anything but returns an empty array. Once `countdown(0)` has returned the empty array, we unshift `1` onto it, and then the log would fire, logging `[1]` to the console.

Comment: my bad, it's just as you say above. Actually passing a .log before the return arr logs *each step* of the recursion to the console (which is useful for learning purposes), but is there a way to specify a console.log(arr) to run **only** when the array is finished, and not within each recursive step?

Comment: @Ferpalaciosd Not really, at least not without needing to change your current function. Logging the array once it has "finished" being populated is what logging the return value of `countdown(n)` will achieve, so you do the log outside of the function. For example `const result = countdown(3); console.log(res);` rather inside of the function.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the array declared as a constant and assigned to the recursion call?

It is not. The array is variable. Every call to this function will return a new array. No arrays get "overwritten". `const` in JavaScript is merely used to declare a *constant variable* which has lexical scope (that is, the variable `arr` ceases to exist after `return arr`) and is *constant* (can't be mutated / assigned to).

> I get the unshifting of the current value, but why is it declared after the recursive call? Shouldn't it be positioned before (one line above) so as to unshift the value before the function loops itself?

You can't position it above since the recursive call is required to obtain `arr` in the first place. After you have counted down from `n-1` to `1`, you must prepend `n` at the first position, which is what `unshift` does.

> Similarly, why is the full final array returned within the else loop? Shouldn't it be better returned outside, or on the base condition above, so as to not be returned every time the function loops?

There is no such thing as an "else loop". The reason for returning the array there as well is that you want `countdown(n)` to return the array it has just generated, using the array `countdown(n-1)`.

> As it is, my understanding is that when n reaches 0, the loop should return an empty array, and not the full array that has been created with the recursion.

That's exactly what `if (n < 1) return [];` does.

---

That said, for the task at hand the recursive implementation given is *highly suboptimal*. First of all, you don't need the `else` since `return` will exit the function anyways:

```js
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) return [];

  const arr = countdown(n - 1);
  arr.unshift(n);
  return arr;
}
```

second, this is most readable (and performant) as a simple `for` loop:

```js
function countdown(n) {
  const arr = Array(n)
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = n - i;
  return arr;
}
```

(bonus: the array size being known ahead of time can be leveraged using the `Array` constructor to prevent JS having to resize the Array as you push elements).

third, the current implementation has **a quadratic time complexity of O(n²)** because `arr.unshift` is a linear-time operation which is applied `n` times to arrays of length `0` to `n-1`.

Recursion is extremely useful when you *need the stack* (f.E. in a depth-first traversal). Creating a countdown doesn't require a stack. This is not *using* but rather *abusing* recursion to implement a highly suboptimal algorithm. If you - for whatever reason (perhaps you are forced to use a purely functional language that has no loops, only recursion?) - wanted to replace the perfectly fine `for` loop with a recursive call at all cost, simply use tail recursion and lexical scope (closures):

```js
function countdown(n) {
  const arr = [];
  function loop(n) {
    if (n < 1) return;
    arr.push(n);
    loop(n-1);
  }
  loop(n);
  return arr;
}
```

or if you don't like closures, what about an optional `arr` parameter? This allows turning the recursion around since the caller now has the `arr` before the callee and can thus append its number before subsequent recursive calls do the same:

```js
function countdown(n, arr = []) {
  if (n < 1) return arr;
  arr.push(n);
  countdown(n - 1, arr);
  return arr;
}
```

same result, but (IMO) cleaner, and most importantly, significantly faster code. Try running all these functions on `n = 1e6` and you will see that the freeCodeCamp one fails to complete in a reasonable timeframe whereas the other ones finish almost instantly.

Answer (score 4):

I would just add to the first part of LMD's answer (I can't comment because of no reputation):

When you define constant array, you are not saying that the array is constant and can't change. You are creating constant reference to that array. So you still can edit its elements, but can not overwrite it with new array.

More info here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_array_const.asp

Answer (score 4):

> **1 -** Why is the array **declared as a constant** and **assigned to the recursion call**? Shouldn't the array be better declared *outside* as a *variable* (since it *changes* value)– and doesn't its current position mean that it is declared (and over-written) *every time* the recursion takes place?

The `const` declaration is block-scoped.  The reference only exists inside the `else`-block.  There is not one generic `arr` that is shared by each call.  Instead, inside of each call to `countdown`, we get an `if`-condition.  If that fails, we create the `else` block and assign a brand-new `arr` variable.  When this is returned, and the function ends, that reference is gone, and only the function return value remains.

> **2 -** I get the unshifting of the current value, but why is it declared *after* the recursive call? Shouldn't it be positioned *before* (one line above) so as to **unshift the value *before* the function loops** itself?

First of all, be careful of "*the function loops itself*".  Recursion is a different mechanism from looping; and although they have equal power, they are not at all the same.

But recall that the recursive call *returns* the result of calling this with `n - 1`.  So

```
const arr = countdown(n - 1);
```

when called with `n` of `4` sets `arr` to `[3, 2, 1]`.  Now that we have this value, we can do the `unshift` operation on it.

> **3 -** Similarly, why is the full final array returned *within the else loop*? Shouldn't it be better returned outside, or **on the base condition above**, so as to not be returned *every time* the function loops?

Again, you need to stop thinking in terms of looping.

Here's an alternative way of thinking about it:  For any smaller value of `n` than our current value, we assume that `countdown` will magically provide us the correct answer, and then, when we call it, we will prepend our `n` value to the result.

Recursion is simply the trick of making that magic work.  If we know the answer to our simpler problem(s) and we can use these to build the answers to our more complex ones, then all we need is a way to stop breaking down into smaller problems: our base cases.

So, for `countdown (3)`, we call our magical `countdown (2)` function, which returns `[2, 1]` and use `unshift` to prepend `3` and get `[3, 2, 1]`.  Of course if we wanted to dig into how that magical `countdown (2)` actually worked, we could and we'd see that it called the magical `countdown (1)`, getting `[1]` and prepended `2` to get `[2, 1]`, and so on.  The magic, it turns out, is rather mundane.

But that's what recursion is, at its core: the notion that there is a sequence of simpler and simpler problems, bottoming out in some base case(s), and that we can build our more complex result based on those simpler ones.  But while writing the logic to do this, it's easiest to think of those simpler ones as magical.